# .htaccess directive exception for html to php in subfolder

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website in whci I redirect all pages with .html to the 'same name.php'.

```
RedirectMatch (.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

But I have one subfolder with an index.html and using no php, so Apache requests index.php resulting in a 404 error. I used a workaround by making a dummy index.php reading the html file and spitting out the html to the browser.
I tried a 'neat' approach with a new .htaccess in the folder of index.html:

```
RedirectMatch (.*)\.html$ $1.html
```

but that results in cyclic redrection 'too many redirects' of which I was already afraid.

Is there a way to make an exception for such a folder that index.html does not redirect in this particular folder ?

BTW I use Apache 2.4.x. It happens on macOS, Ubuntu and Android (KSWEB).

Answer (score 0):

I tried a 'neat' approach with a new .htaccess in the folder of index.html:

```
RedirectMatch (.*)\.html$ $1.html
```

Your `RedirectMatch` will obviously  cause a `RedirectLoop` since both the pattern and the destination are identical. Your `RedirectMatch` redirects `/file.html` to itself that is why the Loop error occurred.

If you do not want to redirect  `index.html` to `/index.php` you can use a `look ahead` based regex pattern which matches all html files except `index.html` .

```
RedirectMatch ((?!index).+)\.html$ $1.php
```